# Php server response to android when executing a batch file

Tags: php, android, response

I have an application which is in java & i have created a batch file(.bat) of that application & running it in php like this

```
   <?php
      system ("cmd.exe /c final.bat");
   ?>
```

The output is something like this

C:\wamp\www\php>java -jar Most closely reseambling is this...C:\wamp\www\php>pause Press any key to continue . . .

I am invoking this through my android application & want this out as response...Can you tell me how to do this .... It would be great if I would be able to eliminate prompts from response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [exec function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Instead of automatically printing the output, it will return the output as a string, or in an optional array of lines in the second argument. You can then parse this string or array and print only what you need.

Example which would print all but the first line of output:

```
exec('cmd.exe /c final.bat',$output);
for($i = 1; $i < count($output); ++$i) echo $output[$i],'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

`system` returns any output from the command, so a simple

```
echo system(...);
```

would do the trick. To be able to send text as input to the invoked command, you should look into using [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen) instead, which lets you "use" the invoked command as if you were using it from a shell/command prompt.

Note that `system` will block until the external program finishes. In your case, with it sitting there with "press any key to continue", this will never happen and your PHP process will just sit there indefinitely (or until `max_execution_time` is exceeded, whichever comes first).

Comment: When i say echo system(cmd)...the output is like "C:\wamp\www\php>java -jar Most closely reseambling is this...C:\wamp\www\php>pause Press any key to continue Press any key to continue. "....Only the last line is repeated....popen didnt help either ...my problem is to keep only my output & remove all other details