# php system return type

Tags: php, batch-file

When I execute my batch file in php, for example:

```
<?php
  system("cmd");
?>
```

I get some output on the browser. The entire command prompt window is printed, like
`C:>wamp>www>php......output...press any key to continue.`

I cant think of any logic to extract my output from this. When I `echo system("cmd");`, I get the same output as above with the last line repeating itself. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: In Windows, isn't cmd.exe the shell itself? So by doing `system("cmd")` you're just spawning a shell, prompt and all? Note I'm not really a Windows user and don't know the internals that well.

Comment: @Michael that is exactly correct.

Comment: What command are you hoping to run, or are you intending to spawn a windows command shell from within PHP?

Comment: Isn't this almost a duplicate of your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967418/php-server-response-to-android-when-executing-a-batch-file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the output, you should use the shell_exec function instead.

Answer (score 0):

[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) displays the output of commands it executes, line by line.

[exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does not display the output. exec includes an option to capture the output to an array, one entry for each line of you need it.

They both produce a return value of the last line of output, which is why `echo system('cmd')` prints the last line twice - it's displaying the output, then printing the return value.

Try using `exec`.